# ajax Post gets stuck in a "Post" state

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-post

I am having an issue when doing a Post with ajax. I have both a "success" and an "error" function.Unfortunately my post never reaches either function and it stays in a "Post" state. I believe it's a network issue and if so what can I do to catch that and attempt to post again. I don't want to create multiple records by posting multiple times though.

Comment: please post what have you done in the code

Comment: can you share what you have done so far, as without looking at the code it's hard to tell anything

Comment: Beside the code; are you sure the call is being made?

Comment: please post the code here. Does it initiates ajax request? Did you check in network tab with developer tool ?

Comment: It may be a server side error that the request doesn't have a response. Try to set the timeout shorter and see what happens

Comment: Added a timeout and that worked like a charm!!
"timeout: 10000"
I am doing this in a web application that switches between access points and I guess there was connection loss for a period of time and that caused the "Post" to hang.

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: url,
 timeout: 10000,
 data: JSON.stringify(datasource),
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (r) {
  alert(r);
 },
 error: function () {
  alert('Error');
 }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an "always" callback function like this example:

```
$.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```